# Failed to claim resource 1 boot error

Tags: boot, dual-boot

After creating a new NTFS partition to share my Firefox profile on a dual boot 64-bit Windows 10/Ubuntu 16.04 system (HP Pavilion Laptop), I had a couple of successful boots before a consistent boot failure with error messages starting:

```
platform MSFT0101:00 failed to claim resource 1
acpi MSFT0101:00 platform device creation failed: -16
/dev/sda6: clean, 827260/57966592 files, 34247978/231861504 blocks
```

...

Does anyone have a suggestion for recovering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSFT0101 is an ACPI device ID referring to the Intel(R) Management Engine Interface (part of TPM).
There are TPM drivers in Linux that can recognize this TPM2 MSFT0101 device ID.
The -16 error number refers to a "Device or resource busy" error in the driver when it gets initialized, so perhaps the TPM device is having some issues.

I believe this is down to Microsoft's requirement that PCs have a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) for newer Windows products.

Comment: looks it is now possible to disable the Management Engine on some motherboard: http://blog.ptsecurity.com/2017/08/disabling-intel-me.html

Answer (score 0):

it is embeded MS license. No issue needed. [See more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj923067(v=vs.85).aspx)