# black screen after do sudo alsa force-reload

Tags: 14.04, alsa

I got a problem with Audio in Ubuntu 14.04, searching on Internet I found a possible solution executing the in the command prompt "sudo alsa force-reload" and rebooting the lap-top but I get black screen and before entry in the black screen shows the following errors:

```
platform MSFT0101 failed to claim resource: 1
platform device creation failed
unknown controller version (3)
```

the Lap-top is Lenovo Y520, Thanks for your help

Comment: You might need to add a `nomodeset i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0` to your grub configuration. You would do that by editing `/etc/default/grub` and changing `"quiet splash"` to `"quiet splash nomodeset i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0"`, and then run `update-grub` and restart. Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: Apparently (https://askubuntu.com/questions/844399/failed-to-claim-resource-1-boot-error), "MSFT0101 is an ACPI device ID referring to the Intel(R) Management Engine Interface." It maybe related to "Microsoft's requirement that PCs have a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) for newer Windows products."

Comment: @darksky It probably doesn't matter but there is also a `nvidia.modeset=0` and maybe a `radeon.modeset=0` too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Yesterday in the night I was searching and I my solution was in the solution of this link askubuntu.com/questions/735898/… after do this commands I do "sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop" And the computer is now ok 
And the problem was not in the Alsa, was in this command:
"sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial"
this command uninstall ubuntu-desktop and other dependences like xserver etc

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.o* /etc/X11/xorg.conf.0* /etc/X11/xorg.conf.f*
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```