# platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resources 1

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 18.04
At boot this message pops up, then Ubuntu regularely starts. Do you know why?
[image: attached]

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/896059/996107. It explains what it is.